# ghc wiki, future features, and lists of types

Tags: haskell, ghc

I was browsing the section of the [GHC wiki on TypeNats](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/TypeNats/MatchingOnNats) when I came upon this really interesting example.  They're creating lists of types:

```
type family Get (n :: Nat1) (xs :: [*]) :: *
type instance Get Zero     (x `: xs) = x
type instance Get (Succ n) (x `: xs) = Get n xs
```

I'd like to find out more about this.  I assume this feature isn't implemented in 7.6.1 (at least it doesn't compile for me), and browsing the tickets proved quite overwhelming.  Any idea what I should look for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code works fine in GHC 7.6, almost -- you need to turn on some extensions, and use ' instead of ` (apparently the syntax has changed?). This example compiles:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

data Nat1 = Zero | Succ Nat1

type family Get (n :: Nat1) (xs :: [*]) :: *
type instance Get Zero     (x ': xs) = x
type instance Get (Succ n) (x ': xs) = Get n xs
```

If you just care about lists of types, and not these TypeNats, you might find examples like this more useful:

```
data HList :: [*] -> * where
  HNil :: List '[]
  HCons :: t -> List ts -> List (t ': ts)
```

As described [here](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.1/html/users_guide/promotion.html). The most relevant GHC extension is `DataKinds`, and the most relevant paper is probably [Giving Haskell a Promotion](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/dimitris/fc-kind-poly.pdf).

Comment: This works fine in GHC 7.4 as well.  (An example of usage: `*Main> :t undefined :: Get (Succ Zero) [Int,Bool,Char]` →
`undefined :: Get (Succ Zero) [Int,Bool,Char] :: Bool`.)

Comment: Sure. But the question specified 7.6. :·)

Comment: I think I get the gist of DataKinds now, but for some reason it's not letting me use the Nat inside a class.  For example, this line from the wiki is also failing to compile for me: `class C (n::Nat) where
  someMethod :: (n::Nat) -> Int`.  Also, that HList is blowing my mind with the `[*]`.  Is that from GADTs or DataKinds?

Comment: You can't use `n` like that -- this `Nat` is a type-level thing, not a value-level thing. `class C (n::Nat) where someMethod :: Blah n -> Int` would work, where `Blah :: Nat -> *`. The `[*]` is from DataKinds -- it's a type-level list whose elements are of kind `*`. See the paper I linked to for more.